# How do you share a link, that have POST data?

Tags: php, html, facebook, share

I am building a website and I am going to add the possibility to share on Facebook, Twitter and Google +. How ever, in some of the sharing codes I have to pass the URL I want to share in a href, the Facebook one gets automatically the actual URL of the page.

My question is: this pages I'm sharing have post data, will the Facebook one work? And what can I do with the other ones that I have to do an href? Is this possible with pages that have post data? If not, what can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Links can only include plain URLs and make GET requests.

That said, if you want to share a page on social media, it almost certainly isn't appropriate to be requiring a POST request to generate that page in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, I will pass the data via get, but now I have the problem of users changing the URL :( @Quentin

Comment: @MarianaHernandez — POST doesn't prevent people from changing the data they are sending.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want that they change the URL that it is the easiest way. Can I change all of the using rewrite rules? @Quentin

Comment: Whatever problem you think stopping people from asking for different URLs will solve, you need to find a different solution for.